# Rust convert iterator over String to &[&str]

Tags: string, rust, iterator, slice

How do I convert an iterator that returns Strings to something that I can pass into a function that takes `&[&str]`? I'm trying to map the iterator to an iterator over `&str`s, but I get an error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to function parameter `s`
  --> src/main.rs:89:52
   |
89 |     let args: Vec<&str> = std::env::args().map(|s| s.as_str()).collect();
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

Why does this error occur? `args` is a local variable in main so surely its lifetime extends to the end of the function and is therefore alive throughout the entire `parse_args` call.

If the function should take a different type I can change it, but I'm under the impression that this type is correct for my purposes - I don't need owned access to a vector, nor owned access to the values.

Here's the code that reproduces the error:

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<&str> = std::env::args().map(|s| s.as_str()).collect();
    let config = parse_args(&args);
    // do stuff with config
}


fn parse_args(args: &[&str]) {
// parse args
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `collect()` twice, first into `Vec<String>` then iterate over that and `collect()` it into `Vec<&str>`:

```rust
let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
let args: Vec<&str> = args.iter().map(|v| v.as_str()).collect();

let config = parse_args(&args);
```

This is because `std::env::args()` returns an iterator over `String`s. If you convert them to `&str`s, they are dropped when we call the next item, and dang! your `&str` is dangling.

So we need somewhere to store the `String`s, and then since we need `&[&str]` and not `&[String]`, we need to iterate over this and collect it again.

Note however, that it is perfectly fine and normal to take `&[String]`. Unlike `&String`, [which is basically useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function) - `&str` is always more flexible, this is not true behind an indirection, such as `&[String]` vs `&[&str]`, precisely because of what we saw now.

If you want to be maximally permissive (for example, for a public function), you can take `&[impl AsRef<str>]`. This will allow both. Then when you use the data, you need to convert it to `&str` using `as_ref()`.